# Guava: Where is CharEscaper?

Tags: escaping, guava

I need to encode a string into Javascript text.

By googling [I found](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/html/HtmlEscapers.java?spec=svn267e41fbf208f6511c513048cbe7f7da25370b24&name=267e41fbf2&r=267e41fbf208f6511c513048cbe7f7da25370b24)  the very useful function `SourceCodeEscapers.javascriptEscaper` which should be in Guava in the `com.google.common.escape.CharEscaper` package.

But it doesn't seem to be there in the actual Guava 13.0.1 release.
(Also [Dzone](http://java.dzone.com/articles/sneaking-peek-guava-release-11) has a note about the new CharEscapers in Release 11, but I cannot find anything about it in the release notes.)

Has the `CharEscaper`-class moved? Was it never in Guava? Will it come in future releases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [not in Guava yet](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=799&q=escape&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Package%20Summary), but it will be.  As I understand it, the API's still being tweaked and refined before we release it and get locked into supporting backward compatibility.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link to the issue. Then I have hope for the next release of Guava.

Comment: It is included in Guava 15

Comment: But unescapers are still missing.

Answer (score 0):

In Guava 20 there are a number of escapers but none that provides a method to escape for JavaScript. Apache Commons [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) provides such a [method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript-java.lang.String-) (including an "unescape" version) and from what I've tested seems to work reasonably well but it is curiously marked as deprecated. Perhaps too complex to deal with authoritatively ??

Just to be clear on the use case, I have used `StringEscapeUtils#escapeEcmaScript` to escape a Java string (JSON string actually) in a way that it could be placed verbatim, as a literal (inside `'`..`'`) in generated JavaScript code and it worked well (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45170939/274677)). Haven't tried the sibling unescape method though.

Comment: It is marked as deprecated because the class has moved to the library `org.apache.commons:commons-text`. It lives in the package [org.apache.commons.text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html).